# i'm getting null value in a child table as a foreign key of parent table using spring data rest or spring data jpa accosiation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhHLm.png)  In this image first address for empId 1 and last two records are empid 2 (empid 2 haveing to address)
file:///home/user/Pictures/fk.png

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "Employee")

public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
private String name;
private Integer sal;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="employee")
private List<Address> addresses;
```

//getter setter

Child entity

```
@Entity(name="Address")

public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer aid;
private String city;
private String state;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Employee employee;

//getter setter
```

Repository

```
@Repository

@RepositoryRestResource(path="employee")

public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {


}
```

Input from RestClient

```
{
  "name":"rdhe",

  "sal":"20000",

  "addresses":[{ 

  "city":"hyd",

  "state":"ts"

  }]
}
```

if i use spring data jpa then code will be 
// jpa Repository

```
public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {


}
```

// EmployeeServer class

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService {

@Autowired
EmployeeRepo employeeRepo;
public void saveEmployee(Employee employee){
    employeeRepo.save(employee);
}
```

}

// controller

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeService;

@PostMapping(path="/save")
public void saveEmp(@RequestBody Employee employee){
    employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
}
```

}

if i'll use spring-data-rest at that time no need to create employeeService and controller class

Comment: Can you share the code of saving the data

Comment: yes let me know your mail

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to share it here?

Comment: i'm talking about to send complete project

Comment: check once i posted  all code

Comment: What is the name of foreign key employee id field in address table, is it fk_empid?

Comment: yes, fk_empid ,  you can change or create entity based on your name i want just insert the data in one to many (bidirectional ) mapping using spring-data-jpa or spring-data-rest

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem until JsonManagedReference came to my rescue.

Try changing your entities to include them like this:

In the Employee Entity:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy ="employee")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Address> addresses;
```

In the Address Entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable =true)
@JsonBackReference
private Employee employee;
```

I was not able to find why it works this way, so please let me know if you come to know :)

Comment: I have been fighting with this for days now.  I had tried every combination of every SO answer I could find.  The only thing that worked was this answer.  I also do not understand why.  It doesn't see related to the database, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the fact that your mentioning `@JoinColumn(name="id")`. The `name` attribute in `@JoinColumn` defines the name of the foreign key field in the child table. Since you are specifying foreign key column as id on hibernate, it could be the issue. Please update it to the same name(ie fk_empid) as specified in database, it should work...

Comment: no sir, i have checked all ready with same name,it's not storing

Comment: Can you share the SQL Queries generated in console then

Comment: Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
 Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
 Hibernate: insert into employee (name, sal, id) values (?, ?, ?)
 Hibernate: insert into address (city, id, state, aid) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Comment: See here is where the issue is  insert into address (city, id, state, aid) values (?, ?, ?, ?).. You do not have id field in your address table as per the screenshot..then why are you not getting any exception..are you connected to correct database?

Comment: previously i was using foreign id as a fk_empid at that time i had taken this screatshot but after that you told me once check with same name(id ) that's why right now fk_empid is id only in table

Comment: you can do one thing once you try in your system to insert data one to many mapping using spring-data-jpa with rest and spring-data-rest then you will get more clarity

Comment: have you try in your system ?